# Android Bluetooth chat application stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, forceclose

I am about to create a Bluetooth Chat app. I installed it on my mobile and when launching it, it shows an error message which contain a Force Close button. My launching activity shows no error. It is given below:

```
package com.group6.abc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter==null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth Is Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    Button btn_start=(Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}       

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        Intent enableIntent=new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent,3);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Is there any error from my side? Anybody please help me.

Thank you...

Comment: Post your LogCat errors, so we can see what's happening.

Comment: It may be a copy/paste error but where is your closing bracket for `onCreate()`?

Comment: Emulator shows no errors. It opens and closes with a TOAST message "Bluetooth Is Not Available". But when I installed it on my phone, it shows the "Stopped Unexpectedly" message with a "Force Close" button.

Comment: @codeMagic 
Sorry... That was a copy/paste error... Corrected it... Thank you... :)

Comment: @Anoop : make sure u have bluetooth on real device and also add logcat result with question when application is crashing on real device to get more help